# Why does the Proxy object reflect changes beyond the target object?

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects, function-prototypes

I wanted to experiment a bit with the [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), and got some unexpected results, as follows:

### Test script

```
function Person(first, last, age) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function () {
  return `Hello my name is ${this.first} and I am ${this.age} years old`;
};
```

So in tracking how the `prototype` object is being modified, I added this wrapper:

```
let validator = {
    set: function(target, key, value) {
        console.log(`The property ${key} has been updated with ${value}`);
        target[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
};

Person.prototype = new Proxy(Person.prototype, validator);

let george = new Person('George', 'Clooney', 55);

Person.prototype.farewell = function () {
  return `Hello my name is ${this.first} and I will see you later`;
};
```

---

### What I expected

```
The property: "farewell" has been updated with: "function () {
  return `Hello my name is ${this.first} and I will see you later`;
}"
```

and nothing else.

And of course, each time I added or removed something from the `prototype`, i.e `Person.prototype` or `instance.constructor.prototype` I expected to see the `console.log()` message.

However I **did not** expect to see anything when setting something on the instance, like:

`george.someProp = 'another value'; // did NOT expect to see the console.log()`

---

### Output

```
The property: "first" has been updated with: "george"
The property: "last" has been updated with: "clooney"
The property: "age" has been updated with: "55"
The property: "farewell" has been updated with: "function () {
  return `Hello my name is ${this.first} and I will see you later`;
}"
```

```
Person.prototype
Proxy {greeting: ƒ, first: "George", last: "Clooney", age: 55, farewell: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
```

It set all the properties on the `prototype` and nothing on the instance, and each time I set something on the `instance` it sets it straight on the `prototype`.

Evidently this is not the default behaviour, as if I remove that `Proxy`, every property set with `this` will be set on the instance itself and the `prototype` will start up empty (or in our case with just the `greeting` function).

What am I missing here ? A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The reason the set trap is being invoked by instance property assignments is due to [section 9.1.9.2 OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor ( O, P, V, Receiver, ownDesc ), step 2.b.i](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ordinarysetwithowndescriptor), where `parent.[[Set]]` is the set trap of the handler object you defined. So trapping properties set on instances of the prototype proxy object is expected according to the specification. I'll write a full answer to explain this when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts! really useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is the fact that when you have a Proxy object in the prototype chain, the set handler will be called when you modify the child object.

In your example, when you set a property on the new instance, the set trap will be executed, the `target` will be the wrapped `Person.prototype` object, but **there's a fourth argument, the `receiver`**. This argument points to the object that the property has been accessed on.

To properly do the property assignment, you can use the `Reflect.set` API to set it:

```
Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
```

That's why the `Reflect` API matches the proxy traps arguments.

So, in your example, we could use the Reflect API and you will see that `Person.prototype` doesn't get "polluted".

```js
function Person(first, last, age) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function () {
  return `Hello my name is ${this.first} and I am ${this.age} years old`;
};


const validator = {
    set: function(target, key, value, receiver) {
        console.log(`The property ${key} has been updated with ${value}`);
        Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver)
        return true;
    }
};

Person.prototype = new Proxy(Person.prototype, validator);

const george = new Person('George', 'Clooney', 55);

Person.prototype.farewell = function () {
  return `Hello my name is ${this.first} and I will see you later`;
};

console.log(george.hasOwnProperty('first')); // true
console.log(Person.prototype.hasOwnProperty('first')); // false
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, if we pass the target, and the receiver in the same order, it should work, check my snippet.

Comment: The output still matches what's in the question, and I think I know why.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, yes, the `set` trap will be still executed, even if you are setting a property on a non-proxy object since the Proxy object is on the prototype chain. The problem that the OP had was that because of this; he was "polluting" the `Person.prototype` object, instead of assigning the properties set on the constructor to the new object instance.

Comment: Yeah, your answer clarified a misunderstanding I seem to have developed with passing the receiver parameter to `Reflect` methods. I left a comment on the question citing the relevant part of the specification where it shows how the set trap is being invoked by the property assignments on instances of the prototype.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts To avoid logging every time an instance is created, you can wrap the `console.log` statement in a `if (Person.prototype == receiver)` so that it will only log modifications of the `Person.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi yes, after having looked at the specification, I would agree with that approach.